How can I use url_launcher to open a URL in a Flutter app?
Future<void> _openURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url, forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: true);
   }

ListTile(
   title: Text('Google'),
   onTap: () {
      _openURL('https://www.google.de/');
   },
);

But no matter what url i want to open, i get the error 'Cant open URL'

I don't know which package are you using for url, but for me the flutter package works fine
Then, just launch the url like this:
_launchUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.google.de/'));

Future<void> _launchUrl(Uri url) async {
  if (!await launchUrl(url)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $url');
  }
}}
                          

Maybe your error depends on the fact that you're using a String and not a Uri type in the function.
Try using the package i told you with the function i provided you.

try adding this Uri.parse(url)
await launch(Uri.parse(url), forceSafariVC: false, forceWebView: true);

package: url_launcher
Future<void> _openURL(String url) async {
 if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
        } else {
        print('Could not launch $url');
        }
}

